# How to filter out weird metadata-like characters from Excel cell

Tags: python

EDIT: please see my own answer as the solution i'm have currently implemented. I'm still open to 'better' or best-practice solutions, if any.

I wrote an application that takes an .xlsx file, reads its content with pandas and uses that data to create objects and push them to the RIPE NCC DB for our administration. These .xlsx files are filled out by our customers. It occasionally happens that the file comes with weird metadata-like characters that are not seen by my application. It seems like data that was copied from another data source, like a PDF file.

For example, a customer has to fill out his phonenumber, i.e. +31 6 12345678. The application does some validation on it and if it passes the validation the value is used further in the script. In this case the application errors when it tries to push it to the RIPE NCC database. I get back the following error: `Severity: Error --> Syntax error in +31 6 12345678?` Notice that the script adds a question mark '?' at the end of the phonenumber.

When copied from the Excel cell to notepadd++, the string 'PDF' is added to the phonenumber:
[image]

I tried the following code, but nothing's changed:

```
import operator as op

allowed_chars = '+0123456789 '
s = ''


phone_number = str(self.pd_keymapping[key][0])
print('PRE validation phone:', phone_number)

for i in phone_number:
    if op.countOf(allowed_chars, i) > 0:
        s += i
phone_number = s
print('POST validation phone:', phone_number)

Output:

PRE validation phone: +31 6 12345678
POST validation phone: +31 6 12345678
```

I can simply fix this by filling out the phone number by hand and rerun the script. But I can imagine that this problem will definitely raise questions when this script is used by my colleagues. I'm therefore looking for a solution that can be handled by the script itself.

What exactly is happening here and how do I filter out these weird characters when reading the Excel document?

Answer (score 0):

The pre validation value of the phone number did in fact return something else than just the phone number. It also returned special unicode characters: `'+31 612345678 \u202c'`.

By just encoding the value to ascii and then decode it again it returned a clean value:

```
value = '+31 612345678 \u202c'
print(str(value).strip().encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode())

OUTPUT: +31 612345678
```